# Spectrum color picker for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, plugins

I need to have color pickers for X elements.  Each element has a different ID.

I am trying to use [spectrum](http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/), but I fail to see how would I initialize dynamically the spectrum for each of my elements.

The elements right now look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="123_my_color">
<input type="text" id="143_my_color">
<input type="text" id="5343_my_color">
....
```

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to select all the elements, then call spectrum on them:

```
<input type="text" class="my_color" id="123_my_color">
<input type="text" class="my_color" id="143_my_color">
<input type="text" class="my_color" id="5343_my_color">
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$(".my_color").spectrum();
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6gU/1/